# Azure AD B2C- PhoneFactor technical profile : phone field is not editable if it prepopulates from inputclaim

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am passing mobile to phonefactor technical profile input claim. If it populates, phone factor making phone field no editable.
I want to prepopulate as well as make it editable

Comment: PhoneFactor is used to secure your identity. Making the field editable will risk the security.

Comment: There is no security risk for my use case. I want to provide user edit phone number with validating new phone by sms or call

Comment: This is signin flow where user login and then in the mfa it will have phone number verification which is non-editable and you want to make it editable for the user. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

For an edit phone number experience, see this example
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/edit-mfa-phone-number